# My python IDE can not run my file. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run something on PyCharm but everything I get is this:

```
Z:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can\'t open file 'C:\Users\zgofer\.PyCharmCE2019.1\config\scratches\exm_fnc_reader.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Based on the error, there's something wrong with the file path you gave it. Without seeing the command your provided or your file system, there's no way of know what exactly the issue is. Why not just run the Scratch within PyCharm though?

Comment: Please provide the command you are using to get the error you are given.

Comment: I didn't brought the code because "exm_fnc_reader " is no my file. I never wrote it so it's probably a system file that read functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it by rightclicking on the file in the project structure (on the left) and selecting "Run" there. Just clicking the "Run" icon on the top right does not necessarily execute the file that is currently open.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong file path when trying to run the script. It looks like the file you are looking for is located in `C:\Users\zgofer\.PyCharmCE2019.1\config\scratches\`. Make sure you are navigating to the correct directory and pointing to the right file when running your script.